# Saying that someone is wacky, airy-fairy, zoned out, distrait, bonkers etc

Tags: sentence-usage

Trying to put up examples that would convey the idea of someone "having a screw loose", "being kooky" etc, I concocted some random sentences containing modifiers interesting for me, which were to some extent chastised by a native speaker who declared them far-fetched and unidiomatic, even incomprehensible.

Could I know which of these words/phrases are appropriate here, forming good collocations?

1. He is a good man, of course, but airy-fairy, in a way. *(He keeps 20 cats at home, which is a good foible by itself)*
2. Notwithstanding his being smart, he is kind of zoned out.(*When someone is kind of a nerd but has a success in studies/sciences)*
3. He was seated in the chair having limped up ahead of time, but he was not welcome there at all and everyone put him down for a punchy. *(He hadn't been a boxer but always comported himself as if he had received too many punches to the head (mentally he was OK)*
4. You'd better not get mixed up with him, he is bat-shit crazy. (*He is in the habit of walloping his girls)*
5. He always gets caught up in different troubles because he is just sick-as-fuck.
6. A bumped off fly was knocking about on the window-sill for more than a week because the housekeeper was distraite (*distracted*), rather bonkers (*silly (with no insult implicated*).

Comment: Hi - questions asking for proof-reading are off-topic here, so your question as it is will probably get shut down. Have you done any research? Or can you state why you think (or why you were told) they were wrong, and include why that information is still confusing you?

Comment: It's not clear what the purpose of these sentences is.  They're obviously all very informal - completely inappropriate for a business reference.  I suspect you are just making up random sentences -- and that's what these are - random sentences. You are using a lot of slang and they are all different meaning.  To make this answerable you probably need to focus the question. Can you find examples of "bumped off", "knocking about" or "bonkers"...  Why and when do you think this would be appropriate?

Comment: _Airy-fairy_ usually describes an impractical idea rather than a person. I understand _zoned-out_ to be a temporary state, nothing to do with a person's intelligence. Unlike Michael, I see _bonkers_ as a harmless synonym for _crazy, silly_ rather than an insult to people with real mental health issues. I'm not even going to comment on your cruder expressions.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker with a good education and vocabulary, and I don't think I've ever heard the word *distrait* before.

Comment: @stangdon - a bit old fashioned. using some French words was considered 'educated' in some circles maybe up to the 1950s E.g. Edgar Wallace (1918) She was a little distraite this morning, for the end of her stay was in sight, and although her visit to England would only be in the nature of a break, and she had resolved to return at the end of six months, she grudged those one hundred and eighty odd days in which she would sink into insignificance, amidst some forty millions of people.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  it occurs to me that I did use *bête noire* in a post the other day!

Comment: Au contraire, pas devant les enfants, au fait, un bon vivant, de rigeur, enfant terrible, fait accompli... my mother used to say _toute de suite_. I once had to explain 'carte blanche' to someone at work.

Comment: @Astralbee That is the point. I forgot to mention that I'm interested in old-fashioned English because it seems more interesting and, I would say, more sumptous, florid to me. But there are hardly any references to be found in dictionaries concerning the extent of words' obsolescence. Once I asked if a certain expression that had already been pointed out as outdated as early as of 1950s could be still used nonetheless, I got an answer that it's more than expedient nowadays.

Comment: [Zoning out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/zone-out) isn't being a nerd.

Answer (score 1):

This question is, before any other consideration, opinion-based, and deeply so. Having said that, I think a reasonably careful (and thoughtful) native speaker might level a number of criticisms against these example utterances:

A. They are all very casual, informal and 'street' or *argotique* as the French say. This may not matter if the level desired is not formal.

B. They, it seems to me, seek to stigmatise people for being or seeming, mentally 'different' in some way. This is a sensitive topic nowadays, e.g. many people would no longer call a person with disability a 'cripple'. In summary, they all come over as cruel and/or thoughtless.

C. Some of the examples use a well-known expression in a slightly odd fashion, as I shall attempt to explain below.

> He is a good man, of course, but airy-fairy, in a way.

Ok really, but a person can be good and 'airy-fairy' at the same time.

> Notwithstanding his being smart, he is a kind of zoned out.

Likewise, but lose the 'a' before 'kind of zoned out'

> He was seated in the chair having limped up ahead of time, but he was
> not welcome there at all and everyone put him down for a punchy.

Stigmatises physical and mental disability. Very cruel. I had an uncle who had been a boxer and had received too many punches to the head. He was a very nice man, and I might have wanted to give you a blow or two if you called him a 'punchy', which is what that means.

> You'd better not get mixed up with him, he is bat-shit crazy.

Not much wrong with this grammatically. Sometimes 'batshit' is written without a hyphen.

> He always gets caught up in different troubles because he is just
> sick-as-fuck.

'Sick as fuck' is an extreme way of describing someone with a very severe personality disorder who is criminally cruel or violent. A serial killer or rapist, especially if children are victims. It doesn't really make sense about someone who just 'gets in trouble' a lot.

> A bumped off fly was knocking about on the window-sill for more than a
> week because the housekeeper was distrait, rather bonkers.

Too wordy. 'Bumped-off' with a hyphen means 'murdered' (of a person). It's a dead fly. Personally, I'd avoid 'distrait', and prefer 'distracted', but if I did go for the French loan-word, it'd be italicised and *distrait* for a man and *distraite* for a woman. Also, being 'bonkers' (cruel term for being mentally ill) does not necessarily explain careless housekeeping.

All in all, they all come over as rather cruel and nasty.

Comment: I think that the "zoned out" one is probably fine, since being "zoned out" is a temporary state of not paying attention to your surroundings - in this case, possibly because they're engaging in complex thought.

Comment: @nick012000 - In the 1990s it was common around me to hear that a young person who was somewhat 'absent' mentally was a [bit of a] _space cadet_.

Comment: @Michael Harvey I have modified the question

Comment: @Eugene you have only made it more silly.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, your examples are all very informal speech. They are appropriate for a casual conversation with friends, but not for, say, a business memo.

Others have pointed out that most of these are pretty rude and in some contexts you could get in trouble for saying such things. If the point is to insult someone, then by definition you're going to be rude. If the goal is to be descriptive and not insulting, most of these would not be appropriate.

But to the real point: I think in most of these cases you're using the phrases incorrectly.

1. "airy-fairy" I haven't heard this term. If it's a phrase you've heard elsewhere. I'm not sure exactly what it's supposed to mean.
2. "zoned out" This means that someone is distracted, not paying attention, so wrapped up in his own thoughts that he doesn't notice what is going on around him. It is a temporary state, not a description of someone's conduct in general. Like, "I tried to talk to Bob and I had to say his name three times before he realized I was even there. He was really zoned out." If you wanted to say that someone was always like this, you'd have to say so, like,  "I don't know what's wrong with Bob. He is zoned out all the time".

"punchy" Used to describe someone who is not fully conscious because he has just been beaten up, or has some medical or other problem that makes him act like someone who was just beaten up. Like, "When Sally fell down the stairs she was pretty punchy for a while." Again, a temporary state.

I don't recall ever hearing someone called "a punchy", as a noun. I've always heard it as an adjective.

"bat-s*** crazy" A general term for someone who acts very strangely. Can be used in many different ways, from, "He's always getting into fist fights. The man is bat-s*** crazy!" to "He actually believes in Bigfoot. The man is bat-s*** crazy!" Note that the use of the vulgarity makes this inappropriate in more polite context.

"sick as f***" Similar to the previous. Could mean "weird" in any number of ways. The f-word is even more offensive than the s-word so this one would be inappropriate in a wider variety of situations. Fine for talking with your drug dealer friends. Not appropriate at work or at church.

"distraite" I've never heard this word before. My dictionary says it means "inattentive or preoccupied", so it is a real word. Maybe more common in other regions than around me. Because I'm not familiar with the word I can't comment on connotations.

Comment: 'Airy-fairy' is common is UK English - 'adjective UK informal not practical or not based on the situation as it really is - _She's talking about buying an old castle in Ireland. It all sounds a bit airy-fairy to me._ (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: @Jay, Michael Harvey Thank you for your useful replies. Switching to the real point, the fact that English is so different in many parts of the world, leaving apart countries where it is the second language (India etc), makes it extremely hard for the learners to sift, so to say, the appropriate from inappropriate, idiomatic from unidiomatic, to correctly descern obsceneties...Don't judge me too rigidly.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, American English is different from UK English is different from Indian English, etc. I suspect that's a problem with any language spoken in many different places. My company runs international web sites and we have different versions of Portuguese for Portugal than we do for Brazil, etc. There are lots of jokes about confusion caused by different dialects. I don't know that there's an easy solution. If you're planning to live in America, learn American English; if you're planning to live in the UK, learn UK, etc. If you're planning to travel around, you just have to ...

Comment: ... learn the variations. If I, for one, point out that something doesn't mean the same in the US as in the UK, I'm not trying to be nasty about it, and sorry if it comes across that way. If I laugh at a misunderstanding, it's in the spirit of "let's laugh together about this", not "I'm laughing at your ignorance of REAL (that is, American) English".

Comment: @Jay No way was I misunderstanding you)) I very much like older English, obsolete as it may be labelled. But I think that old English (by old English I allude to that of the 20-th century, of course, and I like classical detective stories, American preferably, of 1930s-1980s) being sumptious and florid, is much closer to bringing understanding throughout the English speaking world. Once I asked if a certain expression that had already been pointed out as outdated as early as of 1950s could be still used nonetheless, I got an answer that it's fully expedient nowadays

Comment: (as far as I remember it was the expression "to take knowledge of smth."). And I highly appreciate your inference "let's laugh together about this". And I really don't take in why there should be negative reactions at all to questions from English learners, ridiculous or simple as they may seem, on this site.

Comment: @Eugene - some of the negative reactions were about the cruel nature of the sayings.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sure. But this is a forum about grammar, not interpersonal relations. If the question was, "In this situation, should I call this person I'm annoyed with 'bonkers'?", that would call for an entirely different sort of answer. I've answered many questions on here focusing strictly on the grammar, even though the social or political or religious or whatever viewpoints expressed differ radically from my own.